# How to Create sample  entity class in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to create sample entity class for Employee with following fields
Name,Address,EmailId,PhoneNumber

Comment: your question is very obscure! please clearly define what you want!

Comment: Are you talking about the Entity Framework?

Comment: Ya , I want some simple example to understand the concept clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these quick starters on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399182.aspx

It is not mandatory to create your own entity classes manually, MS provides a wizard to generate the model from an existing DB. So simply add a model to your project and it will generate the entities for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class ClsCollegeData
{
    public string CollegeName;
    public string CollegePapularName;
    public string CollegeShortName;
    public string StreetAddrs;
    public string CollegeMobileNo;
    public string CollegePhone1;
    public string CollegePhone2;
    public string CollegeFaxNo;
    public string CollegeEmailId;
    public string YOS;
    public string CollegeCityName;
    public int CollegeCityId;
    public int CollegeStateId;
    public string CollegeImage;
    public string CollegeManagement;
    public string CollegeDescription;
    public string CollegeNRISeats;
    public string CollegeMQS;
    public string CollegeTrust;
    public int CourseId;
    public string CollegeConatctPersonName;
    public string CollegeConatctPersonMobile;
    public string CollegeContactPersonEmail;
    public string CollegeConatctPersonDesg;
    public string CollegeHostalInfo;
    public int StateId;
    public string CollegeWebSite;
    public int CollegeUniversity;
    public string CollegeEligibilty;
}
```